# User validation in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have implemented a code for user validation in VB.NET. When I enter the user name and password in the textboxes of my form, and click the submit button , no message box is displayed even when I have written a code for it . Is there some problem in the try-catch block or am I missing some lines of code?

Can someone point out what's wrong in this code ?

```
       Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As  System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = " " Then
        MsgBox("Enter a user id and password")
    End If
    TextBox1.Text = userid
    TextBox2.Text = password

    Try
        myconnection = New SqlConnection("server=PARTH-PC\SQLEXPRESS;uid=sa;pwd=demo;database=fc")
        'you need to provide password for sql server
        myconnection.Open()

        mycommand = New SqlCommand("select * from student where user id='" &  TextBox1.Text & "' and password='" & TextBox2.Text & "')", myconnection)
        dr = mycommand.ExecuteReader()

    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally



        If (dr IsNot Nothing) Then

            If (dr.Read()) Then

                MsgBox("User is authenticated")
                Form2.Show()



            Else
                MsgBox("Please enter correct username and password")
            End If


        End If

    End Try

    myconnection.Close()
      End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? Does your Form2.Show() work as expected?

Comment: @Tariqulazam : no the control is not going in that if block ..i dnt knw why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Trim()` and `Length` methods or `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` (.net framework 4) to check empty or zero length string.

```
 If TextBox1.Text.Trim().Length = 0 Or TextBox2.Text.Trim().Length = 0 Then
   MsgBox("Enter a user id and password")
   Return 'Terminate this method
 End If
```

Wrong assignment here,

```
 Dim userid=TextBox1.Text
 Dim password=TextBox2.Text
```

Another issue is use of hard coded sql statement.

```
myconnection = New SqlConnection("server=PARTH-PC\SQLEXPRESS;uid=sa;pwd=demo;database=fc")
mycommand = New SqlCommand("select * from student where [user id]=@userid and [password]=@password",myconnection)
mycommand.Parameters.Add("@userid",SqlDbType.VarChar,30).Value = userid
mycommand.Parameters.Add("@password",SqlDbType.VarChar,30).Value = password

myconnection.Open()
dr = mycommand.ExecuteReader()
Dim isFound as boolean  = false
if dr.Read() Then
   isFound=true
End If
dr.Close()
myConnection.Close()

if IsFound Then
   MsgBox("User is authenticated")
   Form2.Show()
Else
   MsgBox("Please enter correct username and password")
End If
```

Comment: Yes I need to do some serious modifications to my code after seeing ur code..Thanks a lot for the help !! :-)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you do not have Option Strict On, and dr is being created in the Try portion of your Try/Catch block. It is out of scope when you get to your Finally section. You are also swallowing any errors that you may have by not having a throw statement in your catch block.

Try:

```
Dim myconnection as SqlConnection
Dim mycommand as SqlCommand
Dim dr as SqlDataReader
Try 
    myconnection = New SqlConnection("server=PARTH-PC\SQLEXPRESS;uid=sa;pwd=demo;database=fc") 
        'you need to provide password for sql server 
    myconnection.Open() 

    mycommand = New SqlCommand("select * from student where user id='" &  TextBox1.Text & "' and password='" & TextBox2.Text & "')", myconnection) 
    dr = mycommand.ExecuteReader() 

Catch ex As Exception 
    Throw
Finally 
    If (dr IsNot Nothing) Then 
        If (dr.Read()) Then 
            MsgBox("User is authenticated") 
            Form2.Show() 
        Else 
            MsgBox("Please enter correct username and password") 
        End If 
    End If 

End Try 

myconnection.Close()
```

Edit: Additional Links for [Option Strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) and [Option Explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/y9341s4f%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) statements

http://www.readmespot.com/question/o/222370/option-strict-on-and--net-for-vb6-programmers

And a Coding Horror [article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/option-strict-and-option-explicit-in-vbnet-2005.html) by Jeff Atwood

Comment: so should I write dr=mycommand.ExecuteReader() after finally ?

Comment: You need to create it before you go into your Try block. Where are you currently declaring myconnection, mycommand and dr ?

Comment: Ok, I am glad you found your main issue. VB can allow you to shoot yourself in your foot by not having to explicitly declare your variables. It is always a good practice to go into your project settings and turn Option Strict and Option Expicit on. It will tell you if your variables are not declared. I will put a link in my answer for you.

Comment: when i tried ur code I get an error saying that "dr is used before it is assigned a value" so where should I declare dr ? can u help me in this ?

Comment: What I put there should work. dr is being declared before use but without seeing all of your code I don't know for sure. I probably would get your main read logic out of the finally statement. Look at this MSDN article to see how they recomend how to do it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx

Answer (score 1):

this:

```
TextBox1.Text = userid
TextBox2.Text = password
```

Looks wrong. beside that, your are probably not getting any record on the reader (because of that lines).. and that is why you are not getting any result. Anyway using that on the finally block is a waste of overhead.

Also your SQL is wrong, it has a ) more than needed

Comment: ok so should I remove these lines : TextBox1.Text = userid
TextBox2.Text = password ?

Comment: Yes, what is the porpuose of that?? that variables are empty (probably you need option strict and explicit turn on). Also your sql is wrong, look at it...

Comment: ok fine ya the sql query needs to be fixed.. I have an extra ')' brace..  I will fix that..also what do mean by option strict and explicit turn on ? I have come across this for the first time..can u throw some light on this ?

Comment: option strict and option explicit force you to declare every variable in vb.net and also force you to make the conversions explicits. google it ;)